# How to represent ramanujans constant in js

Tags: javascript

I'm in VsCode. Heres my js. I'm trying to use Ramanujan's Constant.

```
const RAMANUJANS_CONSTANT = 262537412640768748.99999999999925007
```

VsCode said that I need to use a BigInt. So I put an n at the end.

```
const RAMANUJANS_CONSTANT = 262537412640768748.99999999999925007n
```

Then it gave me an error and said that it has to be an integer, not a float. Is there some sort of BigDec or another way to represent this number, or is it too big for JavaScript.

Comment: You'll need to use some arbitrary length arithmetic library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a big numbers library like big.js.

You could use big.js either in browser or with

http://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/bode.js.

https://github.com/favio41/big-js